# IOS - AnyObject is not convertible to String when loading core data into a table view?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-data

I use Swift. I can save data into a core data base. And I can even print out the data in a for loop but I can't load it into a table view. I have an empty string array(called subjects) that the table view uses it as a data source but I would like to load the data in a for loop into that array.

**Here's how I save the data:**

```
        var appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
        var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

        var newSubject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Subjects", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject

        newSubject.setValue("" + classTextField.text, forKey: "subjectName")

        context.save(nil)
```

**Here's how I retrieve the data:**
I have an empty string array in the class called subjects.

```
    var appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
    var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Subjects")


    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults =  false

    var results:NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!



    if(results.count > 0){
        for res in results{
            println(res)
            subjects.append(res)

        }
    }else{
        println("0 Results.")
    }
```

So, I can print out the data as you can see in the for loop, but I can't add that res value into my subjects array which is used by the table view. But I get the *AnyObject is not convertible to String* error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:
Sorry, I misunderstood the code.

You need to unwrap the results to an array of Subjects

```
if let resultsUnwrapped = results as? [Subjects] {
  for res in resultsUnwrapped{
            println(res.description())
            subjects.append(res.subjectName)
  }
}
```

Comment: But my problem is that in the for loop i can't add that res value to my subject arrau. the println works fine.

Comment: Also what is the object type for the subjects array?

Comment: it's a string array, this what my tableview uses.

Comment: Well, Results is an array of Subjects, but since its an NSArray swift doesn't know what it is. thus unwrap it to an array of Subjects as above. You'll need to call something on the subject object which is a string then append it into the subjects array something like subjects.append(res.subjectName)

Comment: Use of undeclared type of Subjects

Comment: I'm making a few assumptions here that you do have a Subjects object backing the CoreData model. Perhaps just log out the array of results and find out what the object is.

Comment: yes in my coreData model it is called Subjects but still the error says use of undeclared type of Subjects

Comment: Is the Subject class an obj-c class?

Comment: I don't have a Subject class, and everything is in swift

Comment: here's my project, can you please look at it? it's really a small app. 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwEWdVBLZRtgTHNpMjV5VXFvZUE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You need to create the backing NSManagedObject classes for core data. You should be asking another question on how to do this.

Comment: no, it's not a homework for school, i am making an app where the user can manage homeworks

Comment: This should work. https://www.dropbox.com/s/s737fz8qcet5vpo/Homework%20App.zip?dl=0

Comment: Could you help out with this question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29247367/swift-how-to-get-the-index-of-an-array-that-has-an-initializer