# Swift - How to get the index of an array that has an initializer?

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift, core-data

I am making an IOS app and I use swift. I have an array that I need in order to retrieve data from my CoreData database.

```
 var myList : Array<AnyObject> = []
```

This "myList" array has an item called "Monday". I want to get the index of this item. I tried to use this to get the index, but it doesn't work.

```
find(daysOfWeek, "c")!
```

It gives me an error *'Genetic Paramater cannot be bound to non-@object protocol 'AnyObject''*

This **find** method works fine for normal arrays like this:

```
var daysOfWeek = ["Monday", "Tuesday"]
```

How can I get the index of an item for my myList array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states, `find` can't work with `AnyObject`; so although this won't work:

```
var myList : Array<AnyObject> = []

find(myList, "c")
```

this will:

```
var myList : Array<String> = []

find(myList, "c")
```

Since you're searching for a string, making `myList` into an array of `Strings` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
var shoppingList:Array = ["Chocolate Spread", "Cheese", "Butter"]

var indexOfObject = 0

for var index = 0; index < shoppingList.count ; index++ {
if "Butter" == shoppingList[index] {
    indexOfObject = index
}
}

println("Butter index is \(indexOfObject)")
```

I hope this ll help you to find the index of the object.. I don't there is any function to get index directly bt now i use like above only..

Comment: Yes it works with a simple array but I have a different array, it's an anyobject array:

 var myList : Array<AnyObject> = []

Answer (score 0):

In any case, `find` requires a type that conforms to `Equatable` (i.e. has `==`). `==` is not defined on `AnyObject` (there is no general definition of value equality on objects). However, `==` is defined on `NSObject`:

```
import Foundation
var myList : [NSObject] = []
find(myList, "c")
```